# recording only header image_raw message

Tags: ros-melodic, rosbag, camera, image-raw, usb-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to record using rosbag only the /usb_cam/image_raw/header topic excluding the data.

Tried:

rosbag record -a -x  "/usb_cam1/image_raw/data"

But looks like it is not working. I have more topics to include than exclude so just checking for suggestions

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317239/recording-only-header-image_raw-message/) by [jptalledo](https://answers.ros.org/users/40284/jptalledo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-03-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I would like to record using rosbag only the `/usb_cam/image_raw/header` topic excluding the data.

`header` is not a topic, but a *field*.

Subscribing to fields is not supported, so I'm afraid what you want to do is impossible.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1